# Reference request:classical theory of curves and surfaces in the language of manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

For some reason,I learnt some theory of manifold before I learn classical theory of curves and surfaces (I have read Loring Tu's 'An introduction to manifolds.')Then I want to learn Riemann geometry but I know that Riemann geometry requires classical theory of curves and surfaces.But books on classical theory now seem uncomfortable to me.Maybe I need some book using modern language to inroduce these classical theory.Any help will be thanked.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Michael Spivak's A Comprehensive Intorduction to Differential Geometry, Volume 2. In the first 4 chapters, he discusses curves and surfaces and also the classical works of Riemann and Gauss. Throughout, he explains how to "translate" between the older terminology and the modern one.

Comment: Check the book on Riemannian Geometry by Lee. It is written in modern language, but tackles the curves and surfaces issue directly.

Comment: Check O'Neill _Elementary differential geometry_. There's a PDF available on internet with the revised edition. I haven't read it personally but I've heard good opinions. As you can see in the contents, it's classic differential geometry stuff but with the language of modern differential geometry, specially using Cartan's formalism if I'm not wrong. I also suggest you trying to create your own notes on classic differential geometry using your knowledge in modern differential geometry. Try to particularise what you know for curves ans surfaces.